# How would I make a php if statement update my sql column

Tags: php, html, sql, mysql

I'm trying to give persons over 16 special options on the website I am creating, but I'm struggling to get the PHP to check the age and then change the column to 1 for Yes or 0 for No.

What I've Tried

```
if ($account['age']>=16) {
        echo 'True';
        $sql = 'UPDATE accounts SET o16 = 1 WHERE id = ?';
} else {
        echo 'False';
        $sql = 'UPDATE accounts SET o16 = 0 WHERE id = ?';
};?>
```

I'm using MariaDB SQL at this moment.
It returns the values true or false but it does not change the value of the column.

Comment: (1) you have set the update query string ($sql), but you need to execute it to be effective; (2) I believe you should add a where clause so that the update query looks something like `update accounts set o16=1 where userid=?` so that the system knows which record you want to update

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your feedback. but I've tried that and it's still not updating the column.

Answer (score 0):

But what are you doing about the SQL? You are just doing an update but you don't execute it. Try somethings like this.

```
<?php
    
    // $user_id =  you put users id here, if you want to do it over session or something.
    if ($account['age']>=16) {
        echo 'True';
        $sql = 'UPDATE accounts SET o16 = 1 WHERE id = ?';
        $sql->bind_param('i',//$user_id);
        $sql->execute();
    } else {
        echo 'False';
        $sql = 'UPDATE accounts SET o16 = 0 WHERE id = ?';
        $sql->bind_param('i',//$user_id);
        $sql->execute();
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

use print_r($this->db->last_query()); to see the query and check under SQL execution in database server. You can check where you went wrong.